# How to download an app from Microsoft Company Portal/Intune App using QRCode

Tags: ios, swift, intune

My requirement is to install an app, e.g. a test app developed by me for employees from the Microsoft Company Portal app (iOS only) ([Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/company-portal/9wzdncrfj3pz?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)) using the QR Code. So, I want to scan a QRCode through iPhone and I want company portal app to be opened and show me the app developed by me for download.

I searched in direction of custom URL scheme ([Please check details here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)) for the apps that we develop. Though in the case of Microsoft Company Portal app, I don't have control over the code. I do have the control over the test app available in company portal/Intune.

I also tried the "share" link at download page of app. Issue is that, this link opens the safari browser. User has to login and use MFA to reach the download page. Since user already has "Company Portal App" installed on iPhone, I want company portal app to open and show the app developed by me for download.

Comment: I don't believe that there are any parameters for the "companyportal://" URL scheme that can direct a user to a specific app. I think the share URL is the best you have.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 . You have resolved half of my problem by sharing the name "companyportal://". At least company portal app is opening, with the url scheme. Let me do more research and I will let you know if I find anything useful.